# Difference between *, $, and #

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and see these three operators often.  What is the difference between `*{}` `${}` and `#{}`?

I know they are for accessing data from the MVC but in what context?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [types of expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax) Thymeleaf supports are:

1. `${...}` - **Variable Expressions**.  These are the standard expressions.
2. `*{...}` - **Selection Variable Expressions**.  These are the same as variable expressions, except that they are used in combination with a a `th:object` attribute.  For example, if you have `<form th:object="${form}">`, then the expression `*{field}` resolves to `${form.field}`.  These are mostly used when using `th:field` attributes while creating a form.
3. `#{...}` - **Message Expressions**.  These expressions are mainly used to externalize text.  For example, to provide text in different languages by reading from a messages file.
4. `@{...}` - **Link URL Expressions**.  Used to generate URLs, see the [standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).
5. `~{...}` - **Fragment Expression**. Used to specify which fragment to include, see 
   [fragment specification syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fragment-specification-syntax).

Comment: In a thymeleaf template file I have <input th:field="*{ingredients}" ... />. However, ingredients isn't a servlet request attribute. How it become rendered <input name="ingredients" .../>?

Comment: In your case, *{ingredients} is referring to the ingredients property of the object that is currently in context. This object is specified by the th:object attribute in the form tag.  When the Thymeleaf template is processed, it will replace th:field="*{ingredients}" with name="ingredients", binding the input field to the ingredients property of the form object. This allows the user's input to be collected and stored in the ingredients property when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html) provides very nice examples so give it a look.

In short:

`${}` used for variable expressions. Variable expressions are OGNL expressions –or Spring EL if you’re integrating Thymeleaf with Spring

`*{}` is used for selection expressions. Selection expressions are just like variable expressions, except they will be executed on a previously selected object.

`#{}` is used for message (i18n) expressions. Used to retrieve locale-specific messages from external sources