# How to bind fields in a list to a Thymeleaf form? [Bean property is not readable]

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have an object that can either have two or three repeating sets of fields. It seems like the easiest way to handle that is with a list and a form that will expand or contract with the size of the list.

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error suggesting that Thymeleaf doesn't recognize the variables I'm trying to bind to the main form object. This problem is solved in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list), but for some reason I am not able to get the same results.

## What I tried

### DTO

```
package nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Enums.UnitsEnum;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Speaker;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignmentSource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Data
@Builder
public class UserAlignmentDTO {
    private UnitsEnum units;
    private List<UserAlignmentSourceDTO2> userAlignmentSources;

    public UserAlignment toUserAlignment(PreAlignment preAlignment) {
        Set<UserAlignmentSource> userAlignmentSourceList = userAlignmentSources.stream()
                .map(UserAlignmentSourceDTO2::toUserAlignmentSource)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        UserAlignment userAlignment = UserAlignment.builder()
                .preAlignment(preAlignment)
                .userAlignmentSources(userAlignmentSourceList)
                .distanceUnit(units)
                .build();

        return userAlignment;
    }
}
```

```
package nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Enums.UnitsEnum;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignmentSource;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Speaker;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignmentSource;

@Data
@Builder
public class UserAlignmentSourceDTO2 {

    private String modelName;
    private Integer count;
    private Float distance;

    public UserAlignmentSource toUserAlignmentSource() {

        UserAlignmentSource userAlignmentSource = UserAlignmentSource.builder()
//                .speaker(speaker)
                .count(count)
                .distance(distance)
                .build();

        return userAlignmentSource;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
package nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Controllers;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO.UserAlignmentDTO;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO.UserAlignmentSourceDTO;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO.UserAlignmentSourceDTO2;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.*;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Enums.UnitsEnum;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Services.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.*;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/align")
public class AlignController {

    @Autowired
    private final BrandService brandService;

    @Autowired
    private final SpeakerModelService speakerModelService;

    @Autowired
    private final DspPresetService dspPresetService;

    @Autowired
    private final UserAlignmentService userAlignmentService;

    @Autowired
    private final SpeakerService speakerService;

    @Autowired
    private final PreAlignmentService preAlignmentService;

    // Show pre-alignments
    @GetMapping("/pre-alignments")
    public String showPreAlignments(Model model) {

        // Show pre-alignments in model
        model.addAttribute("preAlignments", preAlignmentService.findAll());

        return "pre-alignments";
    }

    // Add pre-alignment to user alignment
    @GetMapping("/pre-alignment/{id}")
    public String showUserAlignment(@PathVariable("id") Long preAlignmentId, Model model) {

        // Find pre-alignment and add to model
        PreAlignment preAlignment = preAlignmentService.findById(preAlignmentId);
        model.addAttribute("preAlignment", preAlignment);

        // Initialize UserAlignmentSourceDTO2
        int numberOfPreAlignmentSources = preAlignment.getPreAlignmentSources().size();
        List<UserAlignmentSourceDTO2> userAlignmentSourceDTO2s = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPreAlignmentSources; i++) {
            UserAlignmentSourceDTO2 userAlignmentSourceDTO2 = UserAlignmentSourceDTO2.builder()
                    .modelName(preAlignment.getPreAlignmentSources().get(i).getSpeaker().getSpeakerModel().getName())
                    .build();
            userAlignmentSourceDTO2s.add(userAlignmentSourceDTO2);
        }

        // Initialize UserAlignmentDTO and add to model
        UserAlignmentDTO userAlignmentDTO = UserAlignmentDTO.builder()
                .userAlignmentSources(userAlignmentSourceDTO2s)
                .build();
        model.addAttribute("userAlignmentDTO", userAlignmentDTO);

        // Show distance units in model
        model.addAttribute("units", List.of(UnitsEnum.METERS, UnitsEnum.FEET));

        return "user-alignment";
    }

    // Create UserAlignment and calculate result
    @PostMapping("/calculate/{id}")
    public String calculateUserAlignment(@PathVariable("id") Long preAlignmentId, @ModelAttribute("userAlignmentDTO") UserAlignmentDTO userAlignmentDTO, Model model) {

        // Find pre-alignment
        PreAlignment preAlignment = preAlignmentService.findById(preAlignmentId);
//        preAlignment.getPreAlignmentSources().get(0)

        // Convert UserAlignmentDTO to UserAlignment
        UserAlignment userAlignment = userAlignmentDTO.toUserAlignment(preAlignment);

        // Calculate result
//        userAlignment.calculateResult();

        // Save user alignment
        userAlignmentService.save(userAlignment);

        // Show result
        model.addAttribute("userAlignment", userAlignment);

        return "result";
    }
```

### Thymeleaf template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout}"
      th:with="activeMenuItem='align'"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Alignment</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="page-content">
    <h1>User-Alignment</h1>
    <form id="source-form"
          th:object="${userAlignmentDTO}"
          th:action="@{/align/calculate/{id}(id=${preAlignment.id})}"
          method="post">
        <th:block th:each="source,iter : *{userAlignmentSources}">
            <label th:text="${iter.index + 1} + '.'"></label>
            <label>Total [[${source.modelName}]] in array:</label>
            <input type="number"
                   th:field="*{userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].count}">
            <label>Distance from [[${source.modelName}]] to FOH:</label>
            <input type="number"
                   th:field="*{userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].distance}">
        </th:block>
        <label>Unit</label>
        <select th:field="*{units}">
            <option th:each="unit : ${units}"
                    th:text="${unit.fullName}"
                    th:value="${unit}">meters
            </option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Align</button>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Expectation

My expectation is that when the user clicks the Align button, the form will post to the endpoint and be persisted to the database.

## Error

```
Invalid property 'userAlignmentSources[0]' of bean class [nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO.UserAlignmentDTO]: Illegal attempt to get property 'userAlignmentSources' threw exception
```

Comment: You are using Thymeleaf's `${source}` syntax in some places (which looks correct, given your use of `th:each="source,iter...`), but `*{source}` in others (which does not look correct, given your use of `th:object="${userAlignmentDTO}"`).

Comment: In case it helps, see also: [Difference between *, $, and #](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57511424/12567365)

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames . I definitely have some doubts about those, but as far as i can tell my code matches the article I referenced.

Comment: By the way @andrewJames I edited the Thymeleaf template just now and error message to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was missing the proper NoArgs constructor for Thymeleaf.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

From chatGPT:

> Based on the error message, it looks like there is no default
> constructor for the UserAlignmentSourceDTO2 class. That means that
> Thymeleaf is unable to create an instance of this class when it tries
> to bind form data to a UserAlignmentDTO object.